# Jquery Cycle Slider Carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am having problem with jquery cycle carousel to slide vertical with 4 visible items

I have put he slider in  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfL6Q/) to test

```
 $('#list_post').cycle({ 
    timeout:    1000,
    fx:      'carousel',
    slides: '> div',
    speed: 500
  });     
<div id="list_post" class='list-box' data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true" 
data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true" data-cycle-carousel-visible="4">
   <div class="slides"></div>
   <div class="slides"></div>
   <div class="slides"></div>
   <div class="slides"></div>
</div>
```

Slider resize into small width and shows only one item in slide. How to make 4 items visible in slider?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the four items to be visible you can go with alternative way by changing property `fx` to `fade`.

```
 $('#list_post').cycle({ 
 timeout:    1000,
 fx:      'fade',
 slides: '> div',
 speed: 500
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DfL6Q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe someone who wants to solve it.**

If you want carousel structure based [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), you can use [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

Example:

```
<div class="slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=carousel
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-next="#next4"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev4"
    data-cycle-pager="#pager4"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible=5
    data-allow-wrap=false
    >
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
    ...
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg">
</div>

<div class=center>
    <a href=# id=prev4><< Prev </a>
    <a href=# id=next4> Next >> </a>
</div>

<div class="cycle-pager" id=pager4></div>
```